# Parallax image very choppy when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I added a parallax image to my website, but to say the least, it looks very choppy. Whenever I scroll down the page it doesn't give the 3d effect like I want it to.

To see this live, go to this page and scroll down close to the bottom of the site...

[My Parallax image](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index)

I am using this plugin:

[The parallax plugin I am using](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)

I am wanting it to be smooth like it is in this example:

http://www.autopoint.com/products

What is the difference in which their image has the 3d effect and when scrolled down it doesn't look "choppy".

I know this question is somewhat broad, but I am just looking for some ideas as to why mine does this or if anyone has any other sort of plugin that would help with my situation.

Comment: It doesn't look very choppy to you? The text inside of the image doesn't scroll smooth. If you would hold down the scroll on the mouse and gently move down the page, then it looks smooth, BUT if you are using the clicking scroll on the mouse, that is when the text/image looks choppy.

Comment: What do you mean by "choppy"? I do see some white space below the image when I scroll fast.

Comment: On the Autopoint-Site, the Image isn't moving at all, it seems to be fixed. Parallax means, the background moves slower, like on your page. I think it's fine, works well on my Browser at least. You can get the same effect by setting background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: Maybe the white-space is what is making it look choppy to me. It just doesn't set well. It looks fine if I hold the scroll bar and scroll down, but if I use the scroll wheel on the mouse, it looks crazy. Is there anyway to make the text scroll down smoothly over-top of it and get rid of the whitespace? I can add my code if needed.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it on MacBook Pro running Yosemite. It could be your cpu or graphics card. Or you may be scrolling with the scroll wheel, in which the detents of your wheel can make it look like bumps in the scrolling; to rule this out try scrolling using the scrollbar.

Comment: I have looked at it on multiple computers. My home computer has a great graphics card. 

Yes, using the scrollbar makes it look fine, but many users use the scroll wheel. I cannot just tell my users to use the scroll bar to see the effect. I am looking for a proactive solution so this looks fine with the scroll wheel.

Comment: Can you add your code? What are the console messages about?

Comment: Most web browsers don't have built in smooth mouse wheel scrolling. There are plenty of scripts on the web that can give you this affect, [here's one that I use and like a lot ;)](https://github.com/nickzuber/silk-scroll)

Comment: @NickZuber This did the trick! The smooth scroll makes it look awesome! Feel free to create an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most widely used web browsers don't have built in smooth mouse wheel scrolling (like Google Chrome, for example). There are plenty of scripts on the web that can create this effect too;

Here is a cross browser, responsive, and simple to use smooth scrolling script that I created and personally like to use a lot:

[**silk-scroll**](https://github.com/nickzuber/silk-scroll)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments above I see your page scrolls fine if you're using the scrollbar and it gets bumpy using the scroll wheel.

Relax. The detents in your scroll wheel cause the page to scroll a set distance at each "click point" in the circle. The number of lines per "click" can be adjusted, but it's not a good idea to do that, unless you want very slow scrolling.

The point is, there won't be any way to adjust the page so that your users will experience smooth scrolling using the scroll wheel. (Though I have to say that using my Logitech bluetooth mouse I don't see any bumpiness at all.)

Comment: Then how do other parallax effects look fine when I use the scroll wheel? Like the one in that sample site I gave; it looks perfect when using the wheel.

Comment: As I said, both look fine to me using a 3rd party mouse on a Mac, so I can't say.

Comment: That's the thing. Most people do not have quality computer products. They have cheap mouses that came in the box. I know it can be done somehow because I have seen these effects look perfectly smooth before using the same equipment I am using now.

Comment: @Becky: I just tested on a PC using the same 3rd party mouse and both exhibit bumpy scrolling, even though the machine is a high-end workstation with 32 GB of RAM and a very powerful graphics card. Seriously, some problems are simply out of your hands.